# jQuery, smooth scroll to Div by clicking on a <li> item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I guess you are wondering why did I even post this question as there tons of examples available out there. But somehow I cannot get this to work.

So my problem is. I have a `jQuery`function that loops through my `divs` and gets their `ID's`. So here is the loop

```
var linames =["Intro","1925","1935","1945","1955","1965","1975","1985","1995","2005","Now"];
var i = 0;
function getSectionIDs()
{
    $("div.panel-grid-cell").children().each(function() {
        if(linames[i] !== undefined) {
          li += "<li><a href='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"'>"+linames[i]+"</a></li>";           
        }
        i++;
    });
    $("ul.timeline-items").append(li);
}
```

And the following `HTML` structure.

```
<div class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div id="panel-101-0-0-0">...</div>
    <div id="panel-101-0-0-1">...</div>
    <div id="panel-101-0-0-2">...</div>
    ...
    <div id="panel-101-0-0-12">...</div>
</div>
```

So What I want to achieve is. Click on a li Items and have a smooth scroll to respective div. At the moment it just instantly jumps.

Tried about 10 different ways, and still no effect.

Comment: It looks like you are just creating anchor tags, what makes you think it should smooth scroll? Are you using a library of some sort to implement that? If you could create a JSFiddle with your code that would be helpful.

Comment: Yea, thats what I mean, I just gave up. I know that I am currently just jumping to div, without smooth scrolling. I will try and replicate it asap in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, a fully working demo.

```js
$(function() {
  var linames = ["Intro", "1925", "1935", "1945", "1955", "1965", "1975", "1985", "1995", "2005", "Now"];

  function getSectionIDs() {
    var li = "";
    $("div.panel-grid-cell").children().each(function(index) {
      if (linames[index] !== undefined) {
        li += "<li><a href='#" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + linames[index] + "</a></li>";
      }   
    });
    $("ul.timeline-items").append(li);
    $("ul.timeline-items li a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var anchor_id = $(this).attr("href");
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('' + anchor_id + '').offset().top
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  getSectionIDs();
});
```

```css
.panel {
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.panel:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeline-items"></ul>
<div class="panel-grid-cell">
  <div class="panel" id="panel-101-0-0-0">...</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-101-0-0-1">...</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-101-0-0-2">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but for some reason, after i press on an item, for .1 second (roughly) I see the content and the div itself, and then it scrolls. I wonder why

Comment: Bug found, I think the solution is to add `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of your click event. Be aware that your function has `e` as argument. See updated demo.

Comment: great! yes, forgot to override default behaviour of click event! thank you